# sql required n:m relation

Tags: sql, relational-database

How does one implement the conceptual idea:

**"An Article has at least one Author"**

The references seem to become cyclic in nature, i.e ArticleAuthors refers to Article, but then the Article must also refer to the ArticleAuthors...

```
create domain Email varchar;

create table Authors(
       authorEmail Email primary key,
       authorName varchar not null
       );

create table ArticleAuthors(
       article int references Article,
       author varchar references Authors,
       primary key (article, author)
       )

create table Article(
       articleID int primary key,
       articleAuthors ??? not null
       )
```

i.e what do I put in place of `???`

Comment: The article table does not have to have any fields about the author.  Also, if an author changes his email address, you have a problem.

Comment: my bad, authors was meant to refer to 'ArticleAuthors'

Comment: @DanBracuk good point about changing email addresses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL RDBMS generally you can't insert on two table at the same time. So you cant have strict implementation.

You usually define some store procedure to handle the transaction as a whole.

So `Article` dont need a reference to `Authors`.

```
 FUNCTION (articleID, authors[])

     if authors is null then exit function;

     START TRANSACTION

     INSERT INTO Article

     INSERT INTO ArticleAuthors

     END TRANSACTION
```

And you also need a Triggers for `DELETE on Authors` to make sure you dont delete all the authors from one article.

Comment: but my Article requires a reference to `ArticleAuthors` no? the section where i have `???`

Comment: "In RDBMS you can't" That's incorrect. In SQL DBMSs you generally can't but that doesn't mean the same limitation must apply to any or all Relational DBMSs.

Comment: Ok, I fix it. Thanks But maybe you should provide a sample where you can do that.

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus No, you dont need that reference. `Article` only need a PK, and  `ArticleAuthors` will reference `Article`

Comment: So the database scheme can't enforce this requirement, meaning it is up to the insert function/application to check that at least one 'Author' has been provided to the insert function?

Comment: That is correct. As I try to explain you cant insert on both tables at the same time. So in a point in time even smaller the restriction doesnt exist. Is like a case of what is first the `egg` or the `chicken`. You have to handle it manually.

Answer (score 1):

SQL DBMSs generally cannot implement this kind of "at least one" constraint between tables using DDL alone. In principle the answer might be to use a CREATE ASSERTION and defer constraint checking until after both tables are updated. Most SQL DBMSs (all the ones I know of) won't allow that however. It's effectively a limitation of SQL because SQL doesn't support multi-table updates.